# How to get hours only from a timespan

Tags: c#, datetime, timer, intervals, hour

How do I use only hours from `DateTime.Now.ToString()` for setting a value (eg: a price) for two or more intervals?

I want to set a variable `p` differently for every 5 hours.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Hours`?

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("hh")` ?

Comment: Like @HariPrasad wrote, use `ToString("hh");` or better still to use `ToString("HH");` for 24-hour format

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Hour` gives hour from current date

Comment: Can you add more context to what you want?  I suspect there's a different way to solve your _real_ problem.

Comment: Can you please be **more** specific about your problem? A [mcve] would be great to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int p = DateTime.Now.Hour;
```

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you covert to string. If you want both methods, either work.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
System.DateTime currentTime = System.DateTime.Now
int t = currentTime.Hour 
string s = convert.toString(t)
s
```

This is another way of doing it as well

```
string time = currentTime.ToShortTimeString()
```

Comment: @SonerGönül - LOL you're funny! I am using it in my code now

    //Get the current time
    System.DateTime ct = DateTime.Now;

    //Check to see if the log file is there.
    if (!(File.Exists(p)))
    {
          using (StreamWriter FS = File.CreateText(p))
         {
    //If the file is not there, create it.
              FS.WriteLine("Log file created: " + (ct.ToShortDateString() + " " + ct.ToShortTimeString()));
          }
    }

Comment: @SonerGönül - Ok, Iooked and saw my mistakes... :-)


            `System.DateTime currentTime = System.DateTime.Now;`
            `int t = currentTime.Hour;`
            `Console.WriteLine(t);`
            `Console.ReadLine();`